# MS Access ?: How to pull information into a table from another linked table

Tags: ms-access

New to access. Trying to create a DB for my wedding.  Have 1 table listing all individual guest names/addresses/etc.:

(See picture titled "Guests")

[(Pictures HERE)](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8P1JVB7Z8J7UmlFVW9ZVS13cFE&usp=sharing)

and a second 1-to-many table called "Invitations" which gives an ID, reference name, and formal name for each intended invitation:

(See picture titled "Invites")

Then, each guest is linked to one of the "Invites" through a lookup to the invite table:

(See picture titled "Links")

In a perfect world, after linking guests to an invitation, the Number_Invited field would populate with the number of linkages, and the Invite Address information would populate with the address of one of those who are linked.

Right now I can look at the guests list and see all the guests, their individual addresses, and the invite to which each is linked, but what I would really prefer is to be able to print the list of unique invitations (basically the "Invites" table), and have the address information filled in so that we could know what to write on each envelope (ie, the formal "Invitation_Title" and respective address).

I realize I may be asking the tables to do more than they're supposed to, and probably need some sort of report OR that this is terrible DB design in general. But again, I'm new to Access and have no one to ask.  So I apologize for having to ask what I'm sure is a simple question but I absolutely appreciate the help!

ANY help/guidance/suggestions/recommendations would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't help you with the details because I don't have your database design.
You need to try to design a query that joins the needed tables and does the part where you say, "but what I really need is to be able to..."
You said "unique invitations" so you probably need a Group By query.

Grab a nice hot cup of coffee, sit down, and let's begin.
Lay out the table architecture.
You need 3 tables.
1. [tbl_guest] contains 1 RECORD per human.
2. [tbl_invitation] contains 1 RECORD per deliverable INVITATION.
3. [tbl_party] contains 1 RECORD per GUEST-to-INVITATION link.
[1 http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic001.png](http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic001.png)

Create a bare-bones query that links the 3 tables.
[1 http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic002.png](http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic002.png)

Run the query.
[1 http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic003.png](http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic003.png)

Create a bare-bones query that COUNTS the total number of guests per-invitation.
[1 http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic006.png](http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic006.png)

Run the query.
[1 http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic008.png](http://electronrock.com/temp/public/pic008.png)

And there you have it.
The number of guests is the number of records in [tbl_guest], provided said guest is present in [tbl_party].
The number of envelopes for the calligrapher to draw artful lettering on is the number of records in [tbl_invitation].
The heart of the thing is [tbl_party] which links 1 or more GUESTS to 1 INVITATION.
It is ok to collapse this down to 2 tables, by putting field [invitationID] inside [tbl_guest] but I personally don't do it that way because the primary purpose of [tbl_guest] is to list people, not to map people to invitations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've restated my question a bit and posted a link to some screenshots to hopefully clarify my problem.

Comment: Super helpful!  I'm still trying to wrap my head around junction tables and knowing when/how to use them.  The only piece of the puzzle I'm still missing is the addresses.  How can I get one report/table/whatever that shows each "Invite" (no duplicates), who's linked to it, and the address it needs to be sent to?

Comment: The list of each "Invite" (no duplicates) is literally the contents of [tbl_invitation].    If the Florman family comprises 6 people, then there is still just one record for them in [tbl_invitation].

Comment: Ok. I think I see what you're saying. My problem is that I have the addresses entered on the guests table, not the invitations table. Each guest has an address. The ones in the same family (or same invite essentially) are just the same. Maybe I should have put the addresses in the invite table instead?

Comment: Yes, field [address] should be in [tbl_invitation].  I repeat, the number of envelopes for the calligrapher to draw artful lettering on is the number of records in [tbl_invitation].

Comment: Thank you for clicking the "accepted" green check mark.  If you like my answer please also click the arrow up upvote icon.

Comment: One more question if you wouldn't mind:  Right now I have all the addresses in the Guests table - one for each guest.  When I add them to the invitations, how can I select one of the addresses for the invite, and can I have it autopopulate the fields?  I'd rather not have to copy an address over to each invitation as well - then I'd have the addresses stored in two tables.